# Return all nodes from Neo4j database in c#

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I am still very new to programming, but what I am trying to reach for now is a piece of code that will show me all of my nodes in my Visual studio. I connected my c# to my database, but what I can't see why I can't show back my nodes. The .Results is giving an error and I can't see why. My code is looking like this so far. Could someone explain what and more importantly why this piece is not working?

```
class DatabaseConnection
{
    GraphClient dbclient;

    public DatabaseConnection(){
        dbclient = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"));
        dbclient.Connect();

        dbclient.Cypher
        .Match("(type:PhonePart)")
        .Return(type => type.As<PhoneItems>())
        .Results
    }

}
public class PhoneItems
{
    public string PhonePart { get; set; }  
}
```

Comment: Can you include the error that you are getting?

Comment: @AdamBT This is the error the .Results is giving me. Only assignment, call, increment, decrements, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Answer (score 4):

Your issue here is actually with C# syntax, not Neo4j at all.

This error is because you've referenced a property, `Results`, but not told the compiler what to do with it. It's like typing `3` in your code and then just leaving it hanging: do you want it assigned to a variable, printed out, or something else?

All you need to do is assign this to something:

```
dbclient.Cypher
    .Match("(type:PhonePart)")
    .Return(type => type.As<PhoneItems>())
    .Results
```

Like so:

```
var phoneItems = dbclient.Cypher
    .Match("(type:PhonePart)")
    .Return(type => type.As<PhoneItems>())
    .Results;
```

Then, your code will compile.

Next, you want to do something with these phone numbers, maybe like so:

```
foreach (var phone in phoneItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine(phone.PhonePart);
}
```

Hope that helps!